# Uniform Convergence of Composing Functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be a continuous function such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. Consider the sequence of functions $f_n:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ defined as follows: $f_1=f$ and $f_{n+1}=f\circ f_n$ for $n\geq 1$. Prove that if $\{f_n\}_{n\geq1}$ converges uniformly, then $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

As I study analysis, I feel like the problems are becoming less intuitive. For such a problem the only idea I have is proof by contradiction. But I don't know what $\exists x,f(x)<x$ can lead me to. For such a sequence of functions without explicit formula, how can I use uniform convergence? Basically I don't know where to start when I'm presented with such an analysis problem.

Can someone give me some hints and it'll be best if you can explain how you think of the method you use. Maybe if it's too much to ask but in general when we are dealing with this sort of problem, what should we have in mind? My mind is almost empty after reading this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if a recursive relation is given, then taking limits of both sides is usually helpful. It turns out to be very close to what we need, except we need to show that $g([0,1])\supseteq[0,1]$ where $g$ is the limit function. But it is easy to prove that by noting the boundary conditions and the continuity of $g$.

A full solution is

> Suppose $f_n\to g$ uniformly. Then we have $g=f\circ g$ by letting $n\to\infty$ in $f_{n+1}=f\circ f_{n}$. This implies that, for any value $x$ in the range of $g$, i.e. $x=g(y)$ for some $y\in[0,1]$, we have
>  $$x=g(y)=f(g(y))=f(x).$$
>  But $g$ is continuous by uniform convergence, and $g(0)=0$, $g(1)=1$. By intermediate value theorem, any $x\in[0,1]$ is in that range of $g$. Thus, $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: Nice. But the OP asked for hints rather than a full solution.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks. I'm trying to come up something as hints. Hope that will help.

Comment: Thank you both so much!